# Is this function an automorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism, automorphism-group, polynomial-rings

Here is the question I am trying to answer:

Let $D$  be a domain and let $a \in D,$ prove that the map defined by $X \mapsto X + a, d \mapsto d$ for all $d \in D$ is an automorphism of $D[X].$

**Here is my trial:**

Recall that an automorphism is an isomorphism from a mathematical object to itself. So, if we call the given map $\varphi,$ clearly, it is a map $D[X] \to D[X].$ Now, it remains to show that it is $1-1,$ onto and homomorphism.

**First. Showing that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism**

1- we want to show that $\varphi(X + Y) = \varphi (X) + \varphi (Y)$ and the identity function  in the second part of the definition of $\varphi$ is always a homomorphism.

Now, since $\varphi(X + Y) = X + Y + a$ (but then it is not a homomorphism, right? )

**Second. Showing that $\varphi$ is 1-1**

2- Assume that $\varphi(X) = \varphi(Y)$ then $X + a = Y +a$ then by cancelling we will get that $X = Y$ and off course the identity function in the second part of the definition of $\varphi$ is always one-one. Therefore, $\varphi$ is $1-1$ as required.

**Third. Showing that $\varphi$ is onto.**

This is obviously correct.

So could anyone help me in the part of showing the homomorphism please?

Comment: What is that $Y$ all along your trial?

Comment: @AnneBauval a variable in $D[X]$

Comment: So $Y=X$? Or what is a "variable" in $D[X]$? An arbitrary element of $D[X]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the notation $X$ for two different purposes. The ring automorphism $\varphi \colon D[X] \to D[X]$ is the substitution of $X+a$ for $X$ in all polynomials: for $f$ in $D[X]$, $\varphi(f)$ is the following new polynomial: $(\varphi(f))(X) = f(X+a)$.
Explicitly,
$$
f(X) = \sum_{i=0}^m a_iX^i \Longrightarrow \varphi(f) = \sum_{i=0}^m a_i(X+a)^i.
$$
That $\varphi$ is additive and multiplicative says $(f+g)(X+a) = f(X+a) + g(X+a)$ and $(fg)(X+a) = f(X+a)g(X+a)$ for all $f$ and $g$ in $D[X]$.

Quite generally, if $R$ is a ring containing $D$ and $r \in R$, show "evaluation of $D[X]$ at $r$" is a ring homomorphism $\varphi_r \colon D[X] \to R$.
$$
f(X) = \sum_{i=0}^m a_iX^i \Longrightarrow \varphi_r(f) = \sum_{i=0}^m a_ir^i.
$$

You're using the special case $R = D[X]$ and $r = X+a$, but it's good to realize the whole setup works more broadly: evaluation of *all* polynomials in $D[X]$ at a fixed element $r$ of a ring $R$ that contains $D$ gives you a ring homomorphism $\varphi_r \colon D[X] \to R$.

Such evaluation maps are usually not ring *isomorphisms*, but they are in your situation ($R = D[X]$, $r = X+a$), since the map that is the inverse of evaluation at $X+a$ is just evaluation at $X-a$: show the ring homomorphisms $\varphi_{X+a} \colon D[X] \to D[X]$ and $\varphi_{X-a} \colon D[X] \to D[X]$ have compositions in both orders equal to the identity on $D[X]$.

Comment: What is the relation between $\varphi$ and $f$ and $g$?

Comment: Also, I think I am a little bit confused about how to write my map in a succinct way so that I can easily proof the automorphisms ... do you have any advice?

Comment: @Secretly I edited my answer to address your questions.

Comment: In your last 2 lines, are you saying that showing isomorphism here is not by showing 1-1, Onto and homomorphism?(will I find any difficulty in showing any of them?)

Comment: Oh, I think you are saying that showing $1-1$ and onto is by showing the inverses, right? but the multiplicativity axiom of the ring homomorphism I think is not very clear to me. Can you please show it to me?

Comment: Verifying an explicit inverse map, in this case, is simpler than showing the mapping is 1-1 and onto.  Concerning multiplicativity, if the general setting is too challenging for you then try a special case, such as $X \mapsto X+1$ (taking $a = 1$).  You haven't told us where your question is coming from: is this homework? a book you're reading (and if so, where)? somewhere else?

Comment: I think I see how to prove the multiplication, I will have the difference between the $f$ and $g$ is the index of the summation right? but is $(fg)(x) = f(x) g(x)$? I think yes and this will solve it I guess, right?

Comment: It was a discussion, that made me very confused because the map was defined in a bad way as you can see and the speaker was very confident, that is why I decided to post it here.

Comment: How about $\varphi$ when it acts on the identity map? is the identity polynomial is just the constant polynomial $1$?

Comment: Does any domain have multiplicative identity the number $1$?

Comment: Sure $1$ is in a domain, and that should be in every algebra book that discusses integral domains.  As for the other question, the term "identity" is vague: do you mean the multiplicative identity (constant $1$) or $X$ in $D[X]$?  Anyway, I feel like you're overthinking this.  All that's going on is that you take polynomials $f(X)$ and replace them all with $f(X+a)$.

Comment: But in the multiplicative proof, how will the indices work, the 2 polynomials $f$ and $g$ have different indices ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "different indices" or why this issue should occur for multiplication and not for addition.

Comment: I think I just got your point now, sorry for bothering you.

Comment: You are not requred to use different indices.  Two polynomials can always be written with the same indexing set when it is irrelevant to keep track of the degree: just include some leading coefficients equal to $0$: $f = \sum_{i=0}^n a_iX^i$ and $g = \sum_{i=0}^n b_ix^i$. Besides, if $f$ or $g$ is $0$ then there is no degree at all (no nonzero coefficient).